# Colouring aligned math text with macros

Tags: color, align, amsmath

I would like to have coloured text-generating macros that i can use inside an align* environment. However, the two seem conflicting.

Here's a MWE describing the issue.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}


\newcommand{\src}[1]{\ensuremath{\color{RoyalBlue}{#1}}}
\newcommand{\letin}[3]{let~#1=#2~in~#3}
\newcommand{\letinsrc}[3]{\src{let}~#1=#2~\src{in}~#3}

\begin{document}
This is on a single line and it works
\begin{align*}
    \src{\letin{x}{3}{x}}
\end{align*}

Here i want to break the text over multiple lines and it does not work
% \begin{align*}
%   &
%   \src{
%       \letin{x}{3}{
%       \\&
%       x}
%   }
% \end{align*}

This is how it should look like, but the issue is the extra usage of ``src'' inside the macro.
\begin{align*}
    &
    \letinsrc{x}{\src{3}}{
    \\
    &\ 
    \src{x}
    }
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Intuitively, i would just like a macro for setting the colour, no matter where, and a macro for the `letin` construct.
The problem is that the workaround is not modular, it is ... well, a workaround and not a solution.
If i have more colours, i must define multiple versions of `letinsrc` and i must wrap each of the arguments in their own \src.
That leads to tons of nested \src while i would just like a single \src at the beginning of the align*.

Also, in the `letinsrc` command, i cannot wrap the arguments in \src, as there will be the line breaks and alignments ampersands and that won't compile.

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot have a group `{`...`}` spread across `&` within `align` (or `array`, or `tabular`, or ...). That's what you're trying to do with your macro `\src` in the second instance where it doesn't work: `\src{ ... & ... }`. You'll have to break this up into segments like `\src{ ... } & \src{ ... }` or use another method of alignment.

Comment: @Werner ouch. But perhaps there is some other way, e.g., saying "change text to red from now on" before the align (or better, within the align), and then "change text to black from now on" when one is done with it?

Comment: Within `align` each "cell" (between `&`) forms a group with limited scope. That's just the way it is. Yes, you can place the colour change *outside* `align`, but that would affect the *entire* `align`.